# Android - store whether a user account is pro in a secure way

Tags: android

I am developing an Android frontend to a web application using its API.

This Android application will expose some extra features if the user is a 'pro'.

Therefore I need the Android app to acquire the information whether an account is pro. That is done while getting the token. In other words, when the Android application requests a token to the web application via the API, the web application provides also a flag representing whether the user is a pro.

When the Android app gets that piece of information, it stores it in the SharedPreferences, like this:

```
this.sharedPreferencesEditor.putBoolean(Account.PRO_ACCOUNT, isPro).commit();
```

Then the Android app reads that value to decide whether a certain feature is available to that user.

Now, my question is: is that approach easily hackable? I mean, can some clever user work-around this system and get pro-features even if they are not pro-users? How could do that?

Can you suggest a better system to accomplish that?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences are stored in a file and are easily readable.

What you need is a `pro` token that is generated for the particular user. Since this is a Web app and is online it should not be hard to create such token on the server and later verify it by sending it to the server.

Comment: But that would imply that the Android app needs to have an Internet connection available to check whether the account is pro or not. And that is not always the case.

Comment: Or maybe you are saying that I should generate two kinds of tokens and embed the 'pro' information in that?